# How to animate a line to extend from both directions, starting at a point in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure this out. I can only seem to get this to work on hover, but I want it to work when I open the webpage without having to move the curser at all.

Comment: Hello! Please include a Minimal, reproducable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use animations rather than transitions; they can play as soon as the page loads.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: 0.5rem; height: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #222;
  animation-name: extend;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes extend {
  10% {
    width: 0.5rem;
  }
  100% {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

If you would prefer the line to animate only once and stay on it's last frame you can use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`. **See below:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  width: 0.5rem; height: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #222;
  animation-name: extend;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes extend {
  10% {
    width: 0.5rem;
  }
  100% {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: How can I make it extend just once and stay extended? When I remove "animation-iteration-count: infinite;" the line just shrinks again and stays small when the animation is complete.

Comment: Use `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to keep the last frame of the animation on the element. Please accept if this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* styles.css */

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #403d3d, #555555);
    height: 100vh;
}

.loader-line {
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e7e3e3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    animation: loaderAppear 2s linear 1s forwards, loaderAnim 5s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

@keyframes loaderAppear {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
}

@keyframes loaderAnim {
    0% {
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left: 1%;
        right: 99%;
        width: 100%;

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="loader-line"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please address the question in your answer. Your answer would be much better if you explained why your code met the needs of the  question-asker